# Program that takes user input and lists multiples of 7 according to that number (Java)

Tags: java, math, operators, counter

Here is my code to create a program that takes a user input and lists multiples of 7 that relate to that number.

For example: The user inputs 3, I need the output to be "7, 14, 21".

Currently if I enter a number less than 7, the program complies without printing an output, but as soon as I enter 7 or any number higher than 7 then the program compiles and prints exactly what I need it to.

So the problem I need to fix is to be able to enter a number lower than 7 and recieve the correct output.

Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MultiplesOfSeven {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    int j = 0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();

    for(j = 1; j <= n; j++){
        if(j % 7 == 0){
            System.out.print(j + " ");

            for (int counter = 0 ; counter < n ; counter++) {
                System.out.print(j*(2 + counter) + " ");
            }       
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Exam time again I see...

Comment: It is very low that some people try to get a university degree without any effort.

Comment: Trying to get ready for one. Haha... @DKIT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't overthink the loop here. As alternatives, both which mean you can delegate the `%` check, consider

```
for (j = 0; j < n; ++j){
    // output (j + 1) * 7;
}
```

or, the less elegant due to your having to write `7` in *three* places

```
for (j = 7; j <= n * 7; j += 7){
    // output j
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is preventing your programm from printing anythingk, when you enter a number below 7:

```
if(j % 7 == 0){
```

% is the modulo operator.
It says: do what is in the brackets if the number I have counted to (j) has no reminder if I divide it by 7.

So what you have to do is count to the number entered (using a for loop) and print the mulitplication of the current number times 7.

Answer (score 0):

It's not printing anything because when the number you inputted is less than seven and greater than zero, the code inside

```
if(j%7==0)
```

does not get executed. I think your code should be like this.

```
for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        if (j % 7 == 0) {
            System.out.print(j + " ");
        }
        for (int counter = 0; counter < n; counter++) {
            System.out.print(j * (2 + counter) + " ");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MultiplesOfSeven {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            System.out.print(7*j + " ");
        }        
    }
}
```

This is simple solution of your problem. This will work for all cases. Keep code simple good luck.